# How to addObjectsFromArray where the destination is mutable and the source is non-mutable?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

If I have a mutable array "codes" in an NSMutableDictionary "categorize"

```
  NSMutableArray *myMutableArray=(NSMutableArray*)[categorize objectForKey:@"codes"];
```

and I add objects from another non-mutable array "templateCodes" in an NSDictionary "templateCategorize"

```
  [codes addObjectsFromArray:(NSArray*)[templateCategorize objectForKey:@"templateCodes"]];
```

does the codes array become "non-mutable" because I copied elements from a non-mutable array (templateCodes)?

This code works the first time objects are copied, but the second time this code is executed I get an error that the "addObjectsFromArray" selector is not valid indicating the array is non-mutable.

Comment: _does the codes array become "non-mutable" because I copied elements from a non-mutable array (templateCodes)?_ No. There's something else wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it should make your mutable array immutable -- a mutable array can contain immutable objects, so adding objects from another array shouldn't make it immutable. This code works fine:

```
NSArray *theData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"One",@"Two",@"Three",nil];
NSMutableArray *mut = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Four",@"Five",@"Six",nil];
[mut addObjectsFromArray:theData];
NSLog(@"%@",mut);
NSLog(@"%@",[mut class]);
[mut addObject:@"seven"];
NSLog(@"%@",mut);
```

Something else must be going on in your code that I'm not seeing.

Comment: Thanks. Ended up being very hard to track down, but it was related to there being multiple arrays and ensuring some were copied. Seems there were "dangling" pointers to array elements that was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the NSCopying protocol in Apple's documentation :

> Discussion
>
> The returned object is implicitly retained by the sender, who is responsible for releasing it. The copy returned is immutable if the consideration “immutable vs. mutable” applies to the receiving object; otherwise the exact nature of the copy is determined by the class.